# Three State Treeview Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, treeview, checkbox, tree, state

One of the frustrations with the standard TreeView is that you can't show a partial selection to indicate that some of the children are selected.  A partial selection in a complex tree allows the user to easily determine where the selections are, even if the tree is not completely expanded.  A similar idea is used in manu backup programs to allow the user to select the files to be backed up.

Does anyone know of a way to make the checks in a treeview checkbox gray? I want to gray the check of a parent node when some (but not all) of its child nodes are checked.  Kinda like what you see when you are selecting  options to install during a software installation.

I have seen several post, but is older (2000, 2007 year).

I now, in 2010, the better answer possible is required. I use VS 2008 . Net 3.5 , Windows Forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a nice article on code project about just this. [Tri-State TreeView Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/TriStateTreeViewSubmissio.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

I am using this [Tri-State TreeView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/Tri-State_Tree_View.aspx), also from CodeProject. Works just fine - should you need a project more up to date.

Comment: This one is from 30 May 2011.