# Tri-State Checkboxes in WinForms TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a TreeView that allows users to select certain elements of hierarchical data by checking or un-checking each item's checkbox. Currently I disable the box on nodes that have children using the [checkbox hiding technique from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698369/how-to-disable-a-winforms-treeview-node-checkbox), like so:

```
☑ Node 1
☐ Node 2
• Node 3
  ☑ Node 3.1
  ☑ Node 3.2
• Node 4
  ☐ Node 4.1
  ☑ Node 4.2
```

But a better solution would be to use tri-state check boxes for the parent nodes, like this:

```
☑ Node 1
☐ Node 2
☑ Node 3
  ☑ Node 3.1
  ☑ Node 3.2
☒ Node 4
  ☐ Node 4.1
  ☑ Node 4.2
```

Since this functionality was available in Win32, my question is how to do this without drawing the boxes myself (e.g., as a user-drawn control or [using an image list](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/treeviewex2003.aspx?display=Print)). I am not familiar with the Win32 API at all; how would one extend the technique linked above to enable tri-state checboxes on a managed TreeView control?

Comment: Another question in this vein, but didn't show up in the dupe finder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051339/three-state-treeview-windows-forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/TriStateTreeViewSubmissio.aspx)? It seems to do the job. It might be a bit dated, (looks like the article is from 2004), but I'm sure the same principles can be extended to whatever you need to do.

Comment: Hmm... I happened across that, but thought it was license-encumbered for some reason. There's a copyright notice at the top. On closer inspection, though, it may be under LGPL. Will leave the question open for a while to see if there are other options.

Answer (score 12):

This code might help you if you are thinking of drawing the mixed checkbox

```
class MixedCheckBox:Control
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, new Point(0, 0), Bounds, 
            Text, Font, false, 
            System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.MixedNormal);
    }
}
```

This will render:    [image]

Good luck!

Comment: Using CheckBoxRenderer is a good tip -- the subclassing solutions I've seen use image lists. Obviously, images are not going to be as portable as calling the renderer directly.

Comment: And how does one would use it exactly with a `TreeView` control, as OP asked?

Comment: Winforms treeview does definitely not allow subclassing of the shown checkboxes, so this answer isn't one.

Answer (score 12):

There is now a neat looking solution at Code Project, [Tri-State Tree View](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/202435/Tri-State-Tree-View)

I'm just researching at the moment, so haven't yet used it.