# Change parent node checkmark to a box when only some children selected

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, treenode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tri-State Checkboxes in WinForms TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626031/tri-state-checkboxes-in-winforms-treeview)

How can I change the symbol within the parent node checkbox in treeview to a green box instead of a checkmark when only some of the children within the parent node are selected?

Example:

[image]

Comment: I recommend you to use a tri-state treeview. I personally use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/202435/Tri-State-Tree-View) project, and I'm happy with it.

Comment: `Possible Dublicate of` - http://stackoverflow.com/q/5626031/763026. `This question can be voted to closed.` if you do not want to use CodeProject articles, then there is code to create own control too in the same SO post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [this code project that already did the work of creating a TriStateTreeView for you?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22116/Tri-State-TreeView-Control-for-NET-1-1) Otherwise, you need to create your own control anyway

Comment: Its a duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/q/5626031/763026. `I think somebody should vote to close it.`